# Modeling Object connections in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

Suppose i have two classes:

- Order
- OrderItem

What connection is the correct one from the standpoint of DDD?

1. OrderItem containing a field referencing the Order
2. Order having a field - collection of OrderItems

Is a field referencing another object interpreted as a dependency?

I am trying to understand DDD better.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an assumption here and consider your Order class to be the aggregate root.

In that case you would go with the option 2, meaning an Order then would contain a collection of OrderItems. And OrderItems could only be added via Order Aggregate root, ie. via method Order.AddOrderItem().